# Select return into Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to have values returned from a Select feed into another sql statement.

```
CREATE TABLE TempModeData
(
  Mode_ID nvarchar(100),
  MaxDetectRange nvarchar(100),
  MinDetectRange nvarchar(100),
  AvgDetectRange nvarchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO TempModeData(Mode_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT mode_id AS Mode_ID FROM detection_report;
```

Result

```
Mode_ID  MaxDetectRange  MinDetectRange AvgDetectRange
44       Null            Null           Null
63       Null            Null           Null
```

I have this table, now I want to enter the return of this Select Statement

```
SELECT MAX(rng) AS MaxDetectRange FROM detection_report WHERE mode_id=44;
```

Result

```
MaxDetectRange
1234.99
```

I want

```
Mode_ID  MaxDetectRange  MinDetectRange AvgDetectRange
44       1234.99         Null           Null
63       Null            Null           Null
```

Comment: You will probably want to add a `GROUP BY Mode_ID` into your select statement so there is a `MAX(rng)` per `Mode_ID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think below query will help you

For Insert Record

```
INSERT INTO TempModeData(Mode_ID,MaxDetectRange)
SELECT DISTINCT a.mode_id AS Mode_ID,b.MaxDetectRange FROM detection_report a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT mode_id , MAX(rng) AS MaxDetectRange FROM detection_report 
GROUP BY mode_id) b ON a.mode_id = b.mode_id
```

For Update existing Record

```
 UPDATE TempModeData 
   JOIN (SELECT mode_id , MAX(rng) AS MaxDetectRange FROM detection_report 
     GROUP BY mode_id) a
   ON TempModeData.mode_id = a.mode_id
 SET TempModeData.MaxDetectRange = a.MaxDetectRange;
```

Comment: a is alias name of the detection_report table and b is alias name of the sub query result.

Comment: This seems to add rows instead of updating the existing rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also work out the Max, Min & Avg ranges and add them with the original insert for any future records like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TempModeData
(
    Mode_ID nvarchar(100),
    MaxDetectRange nvarchar(100),
    MinDetectRange nvarchar(100),
    AvgDetectRange nvarchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO TempModeData(Mode_ID,MaxDetectRange,MinDetectRange,AvgDetectRange)
SELECT
     mode_id AS Mode_ID
    ,MAX(rng) AS MaxDetectRange
    ,MIN(rng) AS MinDetectRange
    ,AVG(rng) AS AvgDetectRange
FROM detection_report
GROUP BY mode_id;
```

This would save you from having to run furtherer `UPDATE` statements afterwards to add the extra info.